# How to estimate the underlying distribution of two groups?

Tags: distributions, classification

If there is a sample, consisting of two underlying groups of people (meaning that we do not which to which group the people belong), and each group follows a specific distribution, how can we estimate the distribution of these two groups?

In other words, we want to classify the identity of the people into two groups, and at the same time want to estimate the distribution of these two groups. How can we proceed?

Answer (score 3):

This is called a [mixture model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution), where we assume that the data $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is generated from the distribution
$$p f_1(x) + (1-p) f_2(x)\qquad 0<p<1$$and where both distributions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are usually assumed to belong to standard families like the Normal, the Poisson, or the Multinomial distributions.

Comment: how about if p is unknown?

Comment: $p$ is an extra parameter of the mixture distribution and as one of the parameters can be estimated by moments, MLE or Bayesian methods.

Comment: Thank you Xi'an, I will think about this for a while. Besides, how can we verify if the assumption on f1(x) and f2(x) is good?

Comment: You can easily verify the fit by comparing the estimated likelihood at the observed data with the distribution of the estimated likelihood at data simulated from the model.